# Spring Flux and the Async annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-async

I have a Spring Flux application where at some point I need to execute some heavy task on the background, the caller (a HTTP request) does not need to wait until that task completes.

Without reactor, I would just probably use the [Async](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) annotation, executing that method on a different thread. 
With reactor, I am not sure if I should proceed with that approach or if there is already a built-in mechanism that allows me to accomplish this.

For example, given a *Controller* that accepts a *Resource* object:

```java
@PostMapping("/create")
public Mono<Resource> create(@Valid @RequestBody Resource r) {
    processor.run(r); // the caller should not wait for the resource to be processed
    return repository.save(r);
}
```

And a *Processor* class:

```
@Async
void run(Resource r) { 
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");
    Mono<String> result = webClient.get()
                                   .retrieve()
                                   .bodyToMono(String.class);
    String response = result.block(); //block for now
}
```

The HTTP caller for `/create` should not need to wait until the `run` method completes.

Comment: did you add @EnableAsync in the configuration class ?

Comment: I have the @Async annotation working, I am asking whether I should use it with Reactor or not.

Comment: I believe [this one should answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566465/fire-and-forget-with-reactor) your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking for the *fire-and-forget* pattern implementation, you could just subscribe your publisher

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public Mono<Resource> create(@Valid @RequestBody Resource r) {
    run(r).subscribe();
    return repository.save(r);
}

Mono<Void> run(Resource r) {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");
    return webClient.get()
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .then();
}
```

If your publisher executes blocking operations it should be subscribed on other thread with elastic or parallel scheduler.

Comment: Will “run” always complete? Even if the caller stream/thread terminates a lot before?

Comment: It's not clear for me "thread terminates". If you use netty NIO threads, they terminates only on application shutdown/crash. In such case you could lose completion (with @Async situation is the same). I have [a small demo](https://github.com/alex-pumpkin/stackoverflow-demo-1) to illustrate that execution completes after controller returns result. Run StackoverflowDemo1ApplicationTests and see logs.

Answer (score 5):

I did some testing, and I think even using `subscribe()` as fire and forget will wait for request to complete before returning an answer to the webbrowser or REST-client (at least in my simple tests, it looks like that).  So, you have to do the similar of @Async, create another thread:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public Mono<Resource> create(@Valid @RequestBody Resource r) {
    return processor.run(r)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()) // put eveything above this line on another thread
    .doOnNext(string -> repository.save(r)); // persist "r", not changing it, though

}
```

And a Processor class:

```
Mono<String> run(Resource r) { 
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");
    return webClient.get()
           .retrieve()
           .bodyToMono(String.class);
}
```

Comment: Will not this make the caller wait until the `processor#run` method has been executed and completed?